# Trying to get values in HTML table into array in java script using j Query

Tags: jquery, html

I have a table in HTML and I am trying to get the values from the table and put them into a 2 dim array in javascript. To do this I am trying to use jQuery. I am able to get the indices to work, but then when I try to put values into the array I only get the values for the first row and then I am getting the error of "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined" after the first row.I believe it has to do with this line of code:

```
tblinfo[i][j] = $(this).text();
```

example html

```
<table id="create">
    <tr>
        <td> row 1 col 1 </td>
        <td> row 1 col 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> row 2 col 1 </td>
        <td> row 2 col 2</td>
    </tr>
```

the rest of my j Query Code

```
$("#save").click(function(){
    var tblinfo = new Array(new Array());
    $("#create tr").each(function(i){ //go through each row
        $(this).find("td").each(function(j){ //go through each column
            tblinfo[i][j] = $(this).text();
        })
    })
    alert(tblinfo);});
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: try alerting i and j in the loop and see what the values are.

Comment: The i and j's we actually working, but when I put that line of code that I had above I got the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have already created an array for the first row, but not any others. You need to create an array for each row, otherwise, `tblinfo[i]` will be undefined. Also note the preferred array syntax of `[]` rather than `new Array()`. Rather than creating the array in advance, just create it in the row loop as needed:

```
$("#create tr").each(function(i){ //go through each row
    tblinfo[i] = []; //now you can add [j] to this in the next loop
```

[**Live demo (click).**](http://jsbin.com/adESogaL/4/edit)

Comment: That did it! Thanks. I can't believe it was that simple.